# flask error: Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL.(connect flask with database)

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask

I am trying to connect my flask to database but it is showing the below error -405
I am still a learning flask and I am not able to figure out the problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEWFs.png)

app1.py

```
from flask import *
from pymongo import MongoClient


app = Flask(__name__)

client = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")

db = client['STUDENT']

studentdetails = db.DETAILS




@app.route("/crudexample")
def sample10():
    return render_template('studentform.html')


@app.route("/success", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def onsubmit():
    fname = request.form.get('fn')
    lname = request.form.get('ln')
    rollno = request.form.get('regno')
    mob = request.form.get('mb')

    a = {"First Name": fname, "Last Name": lname,
         "Regd Number": rollno, "Mobile Number": mob}

    studentdetails.insert_one(a)

    return "Successfully Inserted"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is my python code for the flask
and my code for html form is as follows:

studentform.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="/success">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="fn"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="ln"><br>
            Regd. No:<input type="number" name="regno"><br>
            Mobile Number: <input type="number" name="mb"><br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Click Here">
       </form>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should differentiate between the `GET` and `POST` methods in your code, if your Flask app is configured to only allow `POST` requests to a certain endpoint and you attempt to make a `GET` request to that endpoint it will raise 405 Method Not Allowed.

For example you can modified little bit with something like

```py
@app.route("/success", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def onsubmit():
    if request.method == "POST":
        fname = request.form.get('fn')
        lname = request.form.get('ln')
        rollno = request.form.get('regno')
        mob = request.form.get('mb')

        a = {"First Name": fname, "Last Name": lname,
             "Regd Number": rollno, "Mobile Number": mob}

        studentdetails.insert_one(a)
        return "Successfully Inserted"
    else:
        # handle the GET request method, this one
        # just returned in the client-side in this template
        return render_template('studentform.html')
```